# How to remove from a HashMap if value is present in Java 8 style

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap

There is a `Map<String, List<String>>`. I want to delete a value from the `List` if the `Map` contains a key.

But is there a way to do it in **Java 8** style? Like maybe using compute, merge or some other new method?

The code to remove element from the List in old style way:

```
public class TestClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("key1", getList());
        map.put("key2", getList());

        //remove
        if (map.containsKey("key1")) {
            map.get("key1").remove("a2");
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static List<String> getList(){
        List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("a1");
        arr.add("a2");
        arr.add("a3");
        arr.add("a4");

        return arr;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can remove the element from the list using Java-8-style: `map.get("key1").removeIf(listEntry -> listEntry.equals("a2"));`

Comment: @deHaar Won’t that throw a `NullPointerException` if the key isn’t in the map?

Comment: @OleV.V.  It won't, because this method removes the value if it is present in the list and returns true, otherwise it just doesn't do anything but returning false.

Comment: I didn’t take your word for it, @deHaar. I commented the line `map.put("key1", getList());` out, inserted your statement and got — `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`. (Sorry.)

Comment: @deHaar your `map.get("key1").removeIf(listEntry -> listEntry.equals("a2"));` is just a verbose version of `map.get("key1").remove("a2");`. It does not handle the case that `map.get("key1")` returns `null` when the key is not present.

Comment: @OleV.V that line is just for removing an element of the list, it doesn't have anything to do with the key of the map...

Comment: @Holger to clarify the matter, my `removeIf` comment was too short and thus misleading. It is to be used **only for removing an item from the list, which is the value of the map**. It has nothing to do with the key of the map and should just replace `map.get("key1").remove("a2");` in *Java-8-style*. Since it doesn't answer the question, I put it as comment. Sorry for misleading by putting too few information.

Comment: @deHaar I already thought that there’s a misunderstanding regarding which (or how many) code it is supposed to replace. Still, using `removeIf` isn’t more “Java-8 style” than using `remove`. By the way, there’s a behavioral difference when there are multiple occurrences of the specified element.

Comment: @Holger I know there is a difference, it even has a return value while `remove` hasn't. I suggest we leave it at that, the question has an accepted answer anyway now.

Comment: @deHaar both, `remove(Object)` and `removeIf(Predicate)` return a `boolean` telling whether the collections has been modified. But yes, we can leave it at that.

Comment: @Holger really? Oh, never noticed... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can avoid the two calls, `map.get()` returns `null` if the key doesn't exist. You just get it to a new variable and perform a null check prior to list element removal, instead of `contains`+ `get`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Map.computeIfPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) but the improvement is questionable:

```
map.computeIfPresent("key1", (k, v) -> { v.remove("a2"); return v; });
```

Comment: Well, it needs only one hash lookup instead of two. But on the other hand, it will not work with immutable maps anymore…

Answer (score 5):

We don’t have to Java-8-ify everything. Your code is fine as it stands. However, if you wish, Karol’s suggestion is fine, and here’s another one:

```
    Optional.ofNullable(map.get("key1")).ifPresent(v -> v.remove("a2"));
```

Opinions differ as to whether this is the wrong use of `Optional`. It’s certainly not its primarily intended use, but I find it acceptable.